# Counting the Lotto number draws which contain consecutive numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Witness a draw of lotto numbers, say '$6$ out of $45$'—or $49$, or $59$, this may vary by locality—and watch out for two (or more) consecutive numbers in the draw,
e.g. $\,\lbrace 3,15,20,26,27,36\rbrace$. This appears to happen fairly often.

> How many draws are there, if a draw consists of $\,k\,$ numbers out of $\,\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace\:$?
>
> Assume that $\,n\,$ and $\,1\,$ are not adjacent, that $k>1$,
>   and that $k\leqslant\frac n2\,$ if $\,n\,$ is even, or
>   $k\leqslant\frac{n+1}2\,$ for odd $\,n$.

The preceding bounds for $\,k\,$ are reasonable upon regarding the draws $\,\lbrace 2,4,\ldots,n\rbrace$ or $\,\lbrace 1,3,\ldots,n\rbrace$.

- My first approach was to choose the consecutive pair first, having $n-1$ possibilities, then drawing $k-2\,$ out of the remaining $\,n-2\,$ numbers, yielding $\,(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}\,$ draws.
  But the associated probability
  $${(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}\over\binom{n}{k}}\:=\:\frac{k\,(k-1)}n$$
  shows this cannot be correct. There must be some overcounting when the secondly drawn $k-2$ numbers are adjacent to the already fixed pair.
- A more weird approach was to consider the random variable
  $$ X(d_1,\dots,d_k):=\sum_{i=1}^k(d_{i+1}-d_i)^2\;\text{ where }d_{k+1}=d_1$$
  on the set of all draws $(d_1,\dots,d_k)$ and somehow exploit that at least one summand equals $1$ when evaluated at a draw of interest. (It's then expected to be smaller than $E[X]$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the stars and bars method:

Drawing $k$ numbers out of $n$ means that you have $k$ 'bars' that you need to place between or at the end of $n-k$ other numbers (which are the 'stars'), i.e the $k$ 'bars' need to be in any of $n-k+1$ spots. Hence, you have:

$$n-k+1 \choose k$$

possible ways to have a draw *without* having any consecutive numbers.  If you want the numbers of draws *with* consecutive numbers, then that is of course that number subtracted from all possible drawing, so that is:

$${n \choose k} - {n-k+1 \choose k}$$

Example: Draw 3 out of 7, i.e $k=3$ and $n=7$

Then you have $4$ numbers not drawn which are the stars:

$$****$$

And now you need to place the 'bars' between or at the end of them, but you cannot place two or more bars in the same spot. That is, place $3$ bars in any of the $5$ open slots:

$$.*.*.*.*.$$

For example, one possibility is:

$$|*|**|*$$

which corresponds to drawing numbers $1$,$3$, and $6$

Comment: @Hanno Yes, they should be the bars.  Good eyes! Just updated it ...

Comment: I find this remarkable: For $\,k=6\,$ out of $\,n=49$ one has
$\binom{49-6+1}{6}\big/\binom{49}{6}=0.50480$, whence draws with consecutive numbers are (almost) equally likely as those without!

Comment: @Hanno Huh!  That's pretty cool, thanks for sharing! It reminds me of the birthday problem in that our (mistaken!) intuition is that the chance of getting consecutives is a good bit less than 50%